# If a linear operator preserves positive functions, then it leaves some linear functional invariant

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following question which I cannot seem to make any progress on:

Suppose that $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ is a linear operator satisfying that $Tf\geq 0$ whenever $f\geq 0$, and $T1=1$. Show that there exists a linear functional $\ell:C[0,1]$ satisfying $\ell(1)=1, \ell(f)\geq 0$ if $f\geq 0$ and $\ell(Tf)=\ell(f)$.

My biggest issue is with the last condition, I just don't see how we know enough about $T$ to construct something that satisfies this. An obvious candidate would be $T^{-1}$ but how do we know that even exists or is well defined?

Comment: $T^{-1}$ cannot be an obvious candidate. In fact $$T^{-1}(T(f))=f=T^{-1}(f)$$ implies that $T$ is the identity operator.

Comment: True. That leaves me further at a loss.

Comment: I don't have a complete solution, but something along the following lines should work: Define $\ell_n(f)=\int T^nf\,dx$ and choose some vaguely convergent subsequence of $(\ell_n)$. The main difficulty is to show that the limit is invariant under $T$.

Comment: @MaoWao: How do you get the boundedness of $\{\ell_n\}$ in $C[0,1]^*$?

Comment: @gerw: If $0\leq f\leq 1$, then $0\leq T^n f\leq 1$ and consequently $0\leq \ell_n(f)\leq 1$. Fo arbitrary $f$ just decompose it into positive and negative part (or first real and imaginary part if you like to work over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: You know that $\int_{0}^{1}(Tf)(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)d\mu(x)$ for some positive Borel measure. And $\|\mu\|\le 1$ with $\mu[0,1]=1$. Might be worth considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your positive operator $T$ is given by a Markov kernel, i.e., $Tf(x)=\int f(y)\,k(x,dy)$ where $k$ is a kernel of probability measures on $[0,1]$. The positive linear functional that you want is given by an invariant probability measure $\pi$, that is, a measure that satisfies $k(x,dy)\pi(dx)=\pi(dy).$ In this case, for $\ell(f):=\int f \,d\pi$ we have $\ell(Tf)=\ell(f)$.

The existence of such a $\pi$ is guaranteed by the Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem, see [What is a stationary measure?](http://www.ams.org/notices/201109/rtx110901276p.pdf) by Alex Furman.

Comment: Great response. Thanks!